How to calculate distance difference between two routes with varying number of coordinates in a DataFrame?
I have a DataFrame with two columns: one for the actual route and the other for the estimated route. Each row contains a list of coordinates [latitude, longitude] of varying lengths. Even for the same route, the number of available points can differ. I have 500 examples of different routes. How can I calculate the difference in Kilometers between both routes to determine if they represent the same route, a similar one, or a completely different one?
For example:
data[0]['estimated_route']=[[-12.11149, -77.04675],
 [-12.11145, -77.04671],
 [-12.11139, -77.04664],
 [-12.11134, -77.04659],
 [-12.11123, -77.04648],
 [-12.11122, -77.04646],
 [-12.11122, -77.04646],
 [-12.1118, -77.04589],
 [-12.11193, -77.04576]]


data[0]['real_route']= [[-12.111973, -77.047275],
 [-12.111933, -77.047236],
 [-12.111811, -77.047122],
 [-12.111683, -77.046984]]


Have you thought about plotting these routes? For example if you plot these data you provided, it is pretty obvious that the routes do not overlap and they are also different in shape. If you want to compare their length in km, you should apply a UTM conversion first, for which you can use pyproj.Proj(proj='utm', zone=17, datum='WGS84') for example, in the pyproj package. Once you have done this you can use the Pythagorean theorem to calculate the sum of distance between subsequent coordinates. On the other hand, it would be worth considering why these differences exist in your data...

I have plot those routes (I have 4000 differents), I have a label that indicates if they are similar routes or not, or 'I dont know'. My objective is to build a model to predict if giving two routes predict if they are similar or not. I thought knowing the distance could be a good point to train a model. What do you think?

As a first step, you should identify where those differences in your data are coming from. I mean things like e.g., the data you have are coming from devices with different sampling frequencies or there is more noise in one of them, etc. Without knowing these, there can not be found an appropriate solution in my opinion, because we (or at least I) don't know what should be handled. On the other hand, if there are no big differences expected, between the routes, I don't think that calculating distance is going to be enough, maybe you should think about angles as well

How does calculating the total distances show the routes are the same/similar? They could go by different paths and still end up going the same distance.

@alfonsomore if the answer is ok, you can close this question

Is your  "differemce in kilometers"  aproach based on an assumption that there are (some) routes with matching (or close) start and end points? For example routes in example do not really intersect - https://i.sstatic.net/A9gfcI8J.png - so for those you want your distance metric to be  ... ? Do you need to consider direction? What's the data source, i.e. are all those route points already snapped to some road network / streets / street intersections or it's more-or-less unfiltered GPS data that can occasionally throw in some glitches and  jump around tens, hundreds or thousands of meters?

You need a strategy to tackle this problem.

First, you need to normalize the number of points in both routes by resampling to a fixed number of points. For that, we will be using : Haversine Formula, this formula calculates the great-circle distance between two points on the Earth's surface given their latitude and longitude.

import numpy as np
from typing import List, Tuple
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

def haversine_distance(coord1: List[float], coord2: List[float]) -> float:
    """
    Calculate the great-circle distance between two points on the Earth's surface given their latitude and longitude
    using the Haversine formula.

    Args:
        coord1 (List[float]): A list containing latitude and longitude of the first point [latitude, longitude].
        coord2 (List[float]): A list containing latitude and longitude of the second point [latitude, longitude].

    Returns:
        float: The distance between the two points in kilometers.
    """
    # Convert latitude and longitude from degrees to radians
    lat1, lon1 = np.radians(coord1)
    lat2, lon2 = np.radians(coord2)
    
    # Haversine formula
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    a = np.sin(dlat / 2.0)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon / 2.0)**2
    c = 2 * np.arctan2(np.sqrt(a), np.sqrt(1 - a))
    
    # Radius of Earth in kilometers (mean radius)
    radius = 6371.0
    return radius * c


Then, interpolate Points to Match Route Lengths
To compare routes, we need to interpolate the routes so that both have the same number of points. You can use linear interpolation or any other interpolation method.

def interpolate_route(route: List[List[float]], num_points: int) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Interpolate a route to have a specific number of points using linear interpolation.

    Args:
        route (List[List[float]]): A list of coordinates, where each coordinate is [latitude, longitude].
        num_points (int): The desired number of points for the interpolated route.

    Returns:
        np.ndarray: An array of interpolated points with the shape (num_points, 2).
    """
    # Original route points
    original_points = np.array(route)
    
    # Generate new equally spaced points
    original_index = np.linspace(0, 1, len(original_points))
    target_index = np.linspace(0, 1, num_points)
    
    # Interpolate latitude and longitude separately
    lat_interp = interp1d(original_index, original_points[:, 0], kind='linear')
    lon_interp = interp1d(original_index, original_points[:, 1], kind='linear')
    
    # Generate new interpolated points
    interpolated_lat = lat_interp(target_index)
    interpolated_lon = lon_interp(target_index)
    
    # Return the interpolated route
    return np.column_stack((interpolated_lat, interpolated_lon))


And finally, we need to calculate the Total Distance Between Two Routes.
We can compute the distance between the two routes by summing the Haversine distances between corresponding points

def route_distance_difference(estimated_route: List[List[float]], real_route: List[List[float]], num_points: int = 100) -> Tuple[float, float]:
    """
    Calculate the total and average distance difference between two routes by interpolating both routes to have 
    the same number of points and then computing the Haversine distance between corresponding points.

    Args:
        estimated_route (List[List[float]]): A list of coordinates representing the estimated route.
        real_route (List[List[float]]): A list of coordinates representing the real route.
        num_points (int, optional): The number of points to which both routes should be interpolated. Default is 100.

    Returns:
        Tuple[float, float]: A tuple containing the total distance difference and the average distance difference in kilometers.
    """
    # Interpolate both routes to have the same number of points
    est_route_interp = interpolate_route(estimated_route, num_points)
    real_route_interp = interpolate_route(real_route, num_points)
    
    # Calculate Haversine distance between corresponding points
    distances = [haversine_distance(est_route_interp[i], real_route_interp[i]) for i in range(num_points)]
    
    # Return the total and average distance difference
    total_distance = np.sum(distances)
    average_distance = np.mean(distances)
    
    return total_distance, average_distance

Here, an example of how to use it :
# Example usage:
estimated_route = [[-12.11149, -77.04675],
                   [-12.11145, -77.04671],
                   [-12.11139, -77.04664],
                   [-12.11134, -77.04659],
                   [-12.11123, -77.04648],
                   [-12.11122, -77.04646],
                   [-12.11122, -77.04646],
                   [-12.1118, -77.04589],
                   [-12.11193, -77.04576]]

real_route = [[-12.111973, -77.047275],
              [-12.111933, -77.047236],
              [-12.111811, -77.047122],
              [-12.111683, -77.046984]]

# Calculate route difference
total_distance, average_distance = route_distance_difference(estimated_route, real_route)

print(f"Total Distance Difference: {total_distance:.2f} km")
print(f"Average Distance Difference: {average_distance:.2f} km")



But is it necessary that both have the same number of points? What about Distance of Frechet?

I thought both had the same nb of points to check the distance

This is far from enough to decide whether the two routes are the same or not
